# Animating a simple 2D line in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I've been reading through guides on the internet, but I haven't been able to find a way to animate a line from one position to a new position.

Apparently this requires "tweening", to create a smooth animation, and isn't built in? And all I ever find is "Check out THIS JavaScript framework that handles that for you!"

Does something exist in vanilla JavaScript (or jQuery) akin to:

```
animateLine(current, target, duration, easingFunction)
{
    move(line.x1, target.x1, duration, easingFunction);
    move(line.y1, target.y1, duration, easingFunction);
    move(line.x2, target.x2, duration, easingFunction);
    move(line.y2, target.y2, duration, easingFunction);
}
```

I want to just iterate through an array of lines, calling `animateLine(lines[i], targets[i], duration, easingFunction)` inside of `setInterval()`.

Comment: you can use jQuery which has an `animate` function (including tweening), but the question is how do you want to animate a line? You could do that using `html5 canvas` and pure `javascript`

Comment: I have `<canvas id=myCanvas/>` and `var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");`.  I haven't been able to find a JS command that just draws a line on the canvas.

Comment: then you should google harder

Comment: "You must be this clever to apply".  I mean, I can draw a line with lineTo(), but that doesn't give me a line object I can animate.

Comment: @Zaaier not to be snarky, but here's one of my results when searching, it should help you get the line, and even other Canvas stuff. Might have what you want. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/

Comment: @sharf Yeah, I was just looking at that.  It looks like it only draws some pixels to the canvas.  I think I need some sort of object handle to be able to animate it.  Maybe I can just recalculate the lines every 20ms and redraw the canvas.

Comment: @Zaaier check out the animation section of that website.

Comment: For best performance I'd suggest you take a look at CSS animations as well.

Comment: @Zaaier in what way are you trying to animate the lines? Would like to make my answer work for you, if it's not working now...

Comment: @inorganik Your snippet works great.  Thanks for the all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of different ways to skin this cat... However, as far as the frame-by-frame animation, you want `requestAnimationFrame`. This function calls whatever you pass to it, and passes a timestamp. Then it's just a matter of changing properties of these "lines" to move them across the screen.

If you were animating an `<hr>` element you could make it absolutely positioned and then just change the `top` amount each frame:

html:

```
<hr id="myLine"/>
```

css:

```
#myLine { position:absolute; width:100% }
```

js:

```
function easeOutQuad(t) { return t*(2-t) };
var startTime = null,
    percent, elapsed,
    duration = 3000,
    end = 400,
    hr = document.getElementById('myLine');

function step(timestamp) {
    if (startTime === null) startTime = timestamp;

    elapsed = timestamp - startTime;
    percent = elapsed/duration;

    if (elapsed < duration) {

        // apply easing fn
        percent = easeOutQuad(percent);

        var frameDist = end * percent;
        hr.style.top = frameDist + 'px';
        // next frame
        requestAnimationFrame(step);
    } else {
        // on complete...
    }
}

// begin
requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oytwdk9s/

If you want to support IE9 and older, you'll need a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) for `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: Wow @Zaaier that is rad! One thing I would suggest is instead of using the setInterval to loop the animation, just set startTime = null where I have the `// on complete` comment and call your animation function again.

Comment: Done.  I wonder if that will fix the horrendous lag that was accumulating as the animation ran.